# JavaScript get call stack arguments from recusrive called function

Tags: javascript, recursion, stack

I wonder, how to get function stack called arguments if function was called as recursive?
If I have a normal functions that each calls another one, it works. But if I'm trying to get
a stack from recursive one, I always get the last passed arguments.

```
function a(p1, p2) {
    b(p1, p2, 3)
}

function b(p1, p2, p3) {
    c(p1, p2, p3, 4)
}

function c(p1, p2, p3, p4) {
    console.log(arguments.callee.caller.caller);
}

a(1, 2)
```

in this case I'll get always the same result:

```
var i = 3;

function a(p1, p2) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments);
    args.push(i);

    while (--i > 0) {
        arguments.callee.apply(arguments.callee, args);
    }

    if (i === 0) {
        console.log(arguments.callee.caller.caller.caller.caller);
    }

}

a(1, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

arguments.callee == the function current called,
the caller of this function always points to the caller function itself,
so in recursive functions your caller won't track back to the top but always point to the same function, e.g.

```
function printBacktrace(fun,stackDepth){ 
    var callee = fun;    
    while(callee.caller && stackDepth > 0){ 
        console.log(callee.caller.name);
        callee = callee.caller ;stackDepth--; 
    } 
}
function f(n){
    if(!n){printBacktrace(f,20)}else{f(n-1)}
}
f(3)
```

this will result in 20 times `console.log`.
Currently I can not find a way to solve this - personally I consider it a mis-design in javascript.